# Unexpected prerequisite skip in GNU Make 4.2.1

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a generic Makefile to use with most of my projects. It should work as follows: only rebuild and link those **.o** files whose **.c** or **.h** dependency has changed. The **.o** and **.d** files are stored in a separate directory called 'build'.

With the help of the official GNU Make manual and some googling I've managed to achieve the desired behavior except for one thing: when I run `make re` I get the error: 
`Assembler messages: Fatal error: can't create build/ft_build_buffer.o: No such file or directory` — the reason for this is that the 'build' directory only gets created whenever the **.d** files are generated, but for some reason the `re` rule simply skips this step and goes on to compile **.o** files straight away! Note: if I run `make clean && make fclean && make all` (which should be the exact same thing) everything works fine.

A few other things: I've tried using the `-MMD` option to generate dependencies on the fly but on my machine that causes the **.d** files to only contain **.c** dependencies. Of course I could just make all **.c** files depend on all **.h** files but that seems like a very sloppy solution.

Feel free to share any other advice/improvements that will make this file more clean and readable, thanks! :)

```py
# Define the C compiler to use.
CC := gcc

# Define any compile-time flags.
CFLAGS := -I./include -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g
#CFLAGS := -I./include -march=native -O2 -pipe

# Define the executable file.
BIN := ft_hexdump

# Define build directory.
BUILD_DIR := build

# Define source files directory.
SRC_DIR := src

# Define the C source files.
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

# Define the C object files.
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

# Define the prerequisite files.
DEPS := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

all: $(BIN)

-include $(DEPS)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.d
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)/$*.c -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.d: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -MM  $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

fclean: clean
    -rm -f $(BIN)

re: fclean all
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to have a rule of `.d`  , if you use `-MD` or `-MMD` with gcc it will auto build them any time the corresponding .c file is built (which will happen any time something changes to change the dependencies for that .c file).  Doing it that way, the `.o` file shouldn't depend on the `.d`

Comment: @M.M I've modified my Makefile to use `-MMD` option instead and, surprisingly, now it works! I'm gonna post the modified version as the answer. Thank you for quick response!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working

Comment: You should read this: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: @MadScientist Ok, I will, thanks! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the modified working version as suggested by @M.M

```py
# Define the C compiler to use.
CC := gcc

# Define any compile-time flags.
CFLAGS := -I./include -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g
#CFLAGS := -I./include -march=native -O2 -pipe

# Define the executable file.
BIN := ft_hexdump

# Define build directory.
BUILD_DIR := build

# Define source files directory.
SRC_DIR := src

# Define the C source files.
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

# Define the C object files.
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

# Define the prerequisite files.
DEPS := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

all: $(BIN)

-include $(DEPS)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -c $(SRC_DIR)/$*.c -o $@

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

fclean: clean
    -rm -f $(BIN)

re: 
    $(MAKE) fclean 
    $(MAKE) all
```